# Why did Noah's wife go to hell according to Quran?

Tags: quran, prophets, jahannam

> "God sets forth an example to those who disbelieve: the wife of Noah
>   and the wife of Lot, they were both under two of Our righteous
>   servants, but they acted treacherously towards them so they availed
>   them naught against God, and it was said: Enter both the fire with
>   those who enter." — Qur'an, Sura 66 (At-Tahrim), ayat 10

Can someone explain to me what exactly did she do that made God angry?

Comment: "acted treacherously towards them" and they were disbelievers

Answer (score 3):

Note that Noah's wife is only mentioned in this unique verse in the Quran, while we can read a lot about Noah's effort for da'wah in the surah [Nuh](http://legacy.quran.com/71), we can also read about his [son](http://legacy.quran.com/11/42-46) -who was a disbeliever- and didn't go on board of the arch (long parts of surat Hud are mentioning the story of Noah).

So what do mufasirin say about this verse?

This is taken from [tafsir ibn Kathir](http://www.quran4u.com/Tafsir%20Ibn%20Kathir/066%20Tahrim.htm)

> - "God sets forth an example to those who disbelieve:*
>
> meaning, the disbelievers who live together in this life with Muslims, their mixing and mingling with Muslims will not help the disbelievers, nor will it avail them with Allah, until and unless they gain faith in their hearts.
>
> - *the wife of Noah and the wife of Lot, they were both under two of Our righteous servants,*
>
> means, they were the wives of two of Allah's Messengers and were their companions by day and night, eating with them and sleeping with them, as much as any marriage contains of interaction between spouses.
>
> However,
>
> - *but they acted treacherously towards (both betrayed) them*
>
> meaning, in the faith, they did not adhere to the faith sent through their husbands nor accepted their message. Therefore, all the intimate knowledge of their husbands neither helped them nor prevented punishment, hence Allah's statement,
>
> - *so they availed them naught against God,*
>
> means, because their wives were disbelievers,
>
> - *and it was said:*
>
> meaning, to these wives,
>
> - *Enter both the fire with those who enter."*
>
> The part of the Ayah that reads, فَخَانَتَاهُمَا (but they both betrayed them) does not pertain to committing illegal sexual intercourse, but to refusing to accept the religion. Surely, the wives of the Prophets were immune from committing illegal sexual intercourse on account of the honor that Allah has granted His Prophets, as we explained in Surah An-Nur.
>
> Al-`Awfi reported from Ibn Abbas,
>
> "They betrayed them by not following their religion. The wife of Prophet Nuh used to expose his secrets, informing his oppressive people whenever any person embraced the faith with Nuh. As for the wife of Prophet Lut, she used to inform the people of the city (Sodom), who committed the awful sexual act (sodomy), whenever a guest was entertained by her husband.''
>
> Ad-Dahhak reported that Ibn Abbas said,
>
> "No wife of a Prophet ever committed adultery and fornication. Rather, they betrayed them by refusing to follow their religion.''
>
> Similar was said by Ikrimah, Sa`id bin Jubayr, Ad-Dahhak and others.

Ibn 'Ashour in his tafsir [at-tahrir wa-tanwir](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=4165&bk_no=61&flag=1) says that this example is set by Allah as a warning for non-Beleivers to show them that they won't have any advocates by Allah no matter how near they are to Believers, so unless they believe they can't seek refuge or help from anybody but Allah. The example shows that this applies even to the wife's of the prophets and is also a sign for the wife's of our Messenger (Peace be upon him) whom have been mentioned at the [beginning of the surah](http://legacy.quran.com/66/1-5) telling them don't be like the wife of Noah or the wife of Lut but do your best to be like the wife of Pharao and Mariam daughter of 'Imran (whom would be mentioned [later](http://legacy.quran.com/66/11)).

The quran doesn't mention the story of Noah's wife in any other place. And based on the story narrated in the old Testament (Genesis) it seems that she has betrayed him after the Noachian flood and Noah didn't know. Ibn 'Ashur also referred to biblical quotes speaking about Noah's wife being on the arch (she was part of the people who were saved and safely left it when they went on board and left it) but the bible -apparently- didn't mention her later. So either she became a non-believer afterwards or Noah married an other wife later whom was not mentioned in the Torah.

All tafsir books i consulted seem in consensus that no wife of any Prophet betrayed him in the meaning of illegal sexual intercourse. And agree on explaining the deception by saying they were non-Believers. In the case of Noah's wife some say that she used to tell people (the non-Believers) that her husband is mad and if somebody believed and followed him she was informing his enemy's about them, so she didn't keep his secret (note the relation between this and the beginning of [the surah](http://legacy.quran.com/66/3), were we are told that a wife of our beloved Prophet (peace be upon him) has disclosed some secret).

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Two of the claims are contradictory. You quoted: "wife of Prophet Nuh used to expose his secrets, informing his oppressive people" and also said "seems that she has betrayed him after the Noachian flood," but there are no oppressive people after the flood!

Comment: @TheZ I think it should be clearer by now.

Answer (score 0):

Because she committed kufr and therefore, she became a disbeliever. "but they acted treacherously towards them" means, they refused to follow the faith of their righteous husbands and outright rejected the truth even though it was made clear to them. It is mentioned in [tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1299&Itemid=122) that, Al-Awfi reported from Ibn `Abbas:

> "They betrayed them by not
>   following their religion. The wife of Prophet Nuh used to expose his
>   secrets, informing his oppressive people whenever any person embraced
>   the faith with Nuh. As for the wife of Prophet Lut, she used to inform
>   the people of the city (Sodom), who committed the awful sexual act
>   (sodomy), whenever a guest was entertained by her husband.''

And Allah knows best.

Comment: they already went to hell so don't change the question title to 'why would' from 'why did'

Answer (score 0):

its important to understand the message behind this verse that its only Allah who has the power to mold the hearts towards the path of salvation. Nearness to a prophet does not entail salvation. If details are not given about any event mentioned in the holy Quran, then the message emanating from the event should be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Many people cite various tafsir about the claim that the betrayal was not sexual, but Allah the Almighty tells that it was. When his son drowned, Noah (pbuh) wanted to know why because Allah had told him that his family would survive:
"My Master. My son is from my family and Your promise is true." (Hud, 11:45)

Allah the almighty responds to him:
"Your son is not from your family, he is (the fruit of) an unrighteous affair. Do not ask Me about the thing about which you have no knowledge." (Hud, 11:46)

That means, his wife had cheated on him and, as a result, this boy was not Noah's family. Could Allah explain this any clearer in the Quran? That boy, whom Noah thought to be his own son, was not his. Is there any other explanation for this?

Comment: If you want to ask a separate question post it as a question, not an answer. The verse is open to interpretation and the stronger opinion among the exegetes is that he was legitimate and that 'not from your family\people' in 11:46 just means that he was not among the believers. One reason for this is that while narrating the story Allah calls him Noah's son (11:42) and hence claiming that he was illegitimate is contrary to what Allah has literally said.

Answer (score -3):

Because she was an infidel, as said in Surat Altahreem, Aya 10.

Comment: Assalamu alaikum.  Brother, your answer lacks details. Please consider improving it.

Comment: Brother : there is no details. Noah's wife is mentioned in Quran in less than a line, only in about two verses. Why ? Because there is no use in giving a lot of attention to this subject. God told us that some woman (or any one) is going to hell because she was infidel. That is all what is mentioned about her, so that is all what is needed to be known. That is not my personal opinion, here i'm quoting the scholars explanations.

Comment: Abu-lahab , the prophet's uncle is going to hell and in Quran there is a whole Surah about him and his wife (Surat Almasad) , why God made him that infidel and not a believer ? That is not our business . The right question to be asked is : what can i do to myself to avoid Hell and go to Al-Ganah ?

Comment: But it looks like as if it's your opinion. Please, consider citing sources or mention the name of the scholar who supports your view. Also, there are some details available in the hadiths. I have quoted one in my answer above.

Comment: Ok, i read your answer and it has no much details, because there is no cited details in the subject in the first place. You wrote a reason as mentioned by Ibn Katheer, and there is another one mentioned by Al-Tabary : she was telling his people that he is crazy.

Comment: All of these reasons are told starting by the arabic words قيل (said) and ذكر (metioned) , with no refrence to Hadith of prophet Mohammad (PBUH) in any Sahih . And that kind of refrences is accepted but not considered in the strength level as Hadith because it can not tracked back to the Prophet . So, yes we go with them but not that much keen .

Comment: There is a lot of questions of this type to be asked: what was the color of the dog of Ahl Al-Kahf ? or even what is thier precies number ? from where in the red sea did prophit Moses crosses the sea ? All of these question and alikes are natural to be asked , but Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) teached us a more important thing, ( .... to be continued)

Comment: or you can name it a "meta question" : before i ask a question , i need to ask my self a meta-question : what is the use of my question to my life ? and he told us excplicitly : do not ask question that has no use in your life.

some muslim came to the prophet and asked him : when the dooms day will come ? The prophet answered him by a more important question : what did you do for your self in preparing for the dooms day ? that what you should be concerned about.

God bless you brother :)

Comment: Unnecessary greetings just add clutter and are heavily discouraged here. We are not a discussion forum: Questions and answers are expected to be focussed and to the point. See also http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/107/22

Comment: What greetings do you mean ?